# Dropdownlist check if index changed by code or by selection

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a `DropDownList` in a project. This `DropDownList` contains a `SelectedIndexChanged` event:

```
private void cbo_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e){......}
```

Is it possible to check if the index was changed in the code, like:

```
cbo.SelectedIndex = placering;
```

, or if the change happened by user interaction?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since DropDownList doesn't have property `Focused` as it is for `ComboBox` control in `WinForms` it's not that easy. One way is to add custom flag, and change its value before changing the `SelectedIndex` property. Inside of event handler you can check for this flag and reset its value :

```
private volatile bool isAutoFired = false;
```

Then somewhere in code :

```
isAutoFired = true;
cbo.SelectedIndex = placering;


private void cbo_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{       
   if(!isAutoFired)
   {
      // event is fired by user 
   }

   isAutoFired = false;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, just what I was looking for!

Answer (score 1):

You could remove the event handler in the code right before programmably changing the selection then add it back right afterwards. This is my favorite approach. No need for flags.

```
cbo.SelectedIndexChanged -= cbo_SelectedIndexChanged;
cbo.SelectedIndex = 1 // or what you do to change the index
cbo.SelectedIndexCHanged += new EventHandler(cbo_SelectedIndexChanged);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ContainsFocus` to check if the control has the focus at time of value changed.

At the top of the event method:

```
if (!((RadDropDownList)sender).ContainsFocus) return;
```

If the control is not focused, that could mean that the value change is happening programatically, so it will quit the method.